# MVC 5 Ajax posting whole form - instead of ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a basic ajax call setup in MVC 5 but it seems that my Ajax form is actually posting the full form, instead of getting back PartialViewResult in the main view, the whole window just renders with the PartialView for the result

suggestion what I may be missing here ?

I also do have the following jquery renders in my _Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

**MainView**

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Puzzles 1 & 2";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<div>
    @Html.Partial("Puzzle1Form")
</div>
```

**PartialView**

```
@model SixPivot_Code_Puzzles.Models.Puzzle1Model


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Puzzle1","Puzzles",new AjaxOptions {
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "puzzle1-result",
}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Puzzle1</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IntegerList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })            
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IntegerList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IntegerList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Find Largest No." class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
}
<div id="puzzle1-result"></div>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]        
        public PartialViewResult Puzzle1(Puzzle1Model model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Puzzle1Model result = new Puzzle1Model();
                result.LargestInteger = FindLargestInt(model.IntegerList).ToString();
                result.IntegerList = model.IntegerList;
                return PartialView("Puzzle1FormResult",result);
            }
            else {
                return PartialView("Puzzle1Form",model);
            }            
        }
```

**PartialViewResult on Success (Puzzle1FormResult.cshtml)**

```
@model SixPivot_Code_Puzzles.Models.Puzzle1Model

<div>
    <h4>Largest Integer</h4>
    <hr />
    <p>
        Largest Integer for the list "@Model.IntegerList" is : @Model.LargestInteger
    </p>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to try not use the Ajax helpers in MVC because I find jQuery easier to understand. You could try doing it how I would.

**PartialView**

```
@model SixPivot_Code_Puzzles.Models.Puzzle1Model


<form class="form-horizontal" id="frmPuzzle1">
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <div>
    <h4>Puzzle1</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IntegerList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })            
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IntegerList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IntegerList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Find Largest No." class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="puzzle1-result"></div>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

*Notice I removed the scripts section, you should have this in your layout instead.

**MainView**

```
@{ 
  ViewBag.Title = "Puzzles 1 & 2";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<div>
    @Html.Partial("Puzzle1Form")
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#frmPuzzle1', function(e) {
      // stop default form submission
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Puzzle1", "Puzzles")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#frmPuzzle1').serialize(),
        success: function(html) {
          $('#puzzle1-result').html(html);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks!, i found that for some reason, when I moved the jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.min.js to _layout - the helpers started working - probably the path from one of my sub view folders was incorrect

Answer (score 2):

The `Ajax.*` family of helpers simply add a standard HTML setup (a regular old form, for example) and some JavaScript that intercepts the default behavior, sending it as AJAX instead. In other words, the code is *unobtrusive*. If for whatever reason the JavaScript can't be run, it will fallback to standard behavior of doing a simple form post.

Therefore, if it's doing a standard form post, rather than sending an AJAX request, you most likely have some JavaScript error on the page that is preventing the AJAX code from running.

Comment: hmm, as far as I can see there's no js error in the console

Answer (score -2):

The Ajax.* family of helpers simply add a standard HTML setup (a regular old form, for example) and some JavaScript that intercepts the default behavior, sending it as AJAX instead. In other words, the code is unobtrusive. If for whatever reason the JavaScript can't be run, it will fallback to standard behavior of doing a simple form post.